# Настройка целей Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста подключили код аналитики, установили цели но к сожалению они не срабатывают, возможно цель установлена неправильно? Вот часть кода с целью

```
<div class="button-1" data-tab-hide=".tabs,.title-quest-box" data-tab-show=".vopros-1" onclick="ga('send','event','knopka18','push18')">
                    <p>ПОЛУЧИТЬ СКИДКУ</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Технически все правильно, если на странице есть код отслеживания google analytics.

1. Возможно вы не там смотрите?  Созданные вами цели будут видны в
   отчете Поведение >> События >> Обзор. А там выбираете по категории
   или действию.
2. Иногда, например, в форме обратной связи, ваше событие не сработает, потому что оно отменяется джаваскриптом через
   preventDefault() после отправки сообщения этой формы. В таком случае
   отправку сообщения нужно вешать перед вызовом preventDefault() или
   модифицировать код отправки ивента в google analytics.